# Samlex power inverter PCB wiring schematic or test points

Tags: inverter

I am trying to find a wiring diagram or voltage test points for a Samlex 1500 watt PST150S-12A inverter board. Losing a/c output, have found a possible short on board. 2 of the 8 output mosfets have drain circuits to ground.

Comment: ask the manufacturer

Comment: Manufacturer will not give out any documents .have contacted samlex already.

Comment: There are manufacturers more willing to stand by their product. Remember that next time.

Comment: i have found out the hard way

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Samlex is a high service company. Call them back and ask what they can do about your failed unit. By the model number it looks like it is a discontinued model so well out of warranty. They have been known to replace with refurbished at little cost, especially if you have a good user story about it.

Comment: Yes it is an older model,contacted samlex twice,was told they no longer support any tech service or board diagnostics.I Have even purchased a new model for my replacement!